# How to have rank of elements in each list after explode the dataframe based on lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas when we explode a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[['e', 'g', 'p'],['c', 'x']]})
```

by command `df.explode('A')` we get

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['e', 'g', 'p','c', 'x']}, index = [0,0,0,1,1])
```

so far so good. but what if rank of elements in each list were meaningful and we want have this rank after explode? and get something like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':['e', 'g', 'p','c', 'x'], 'Rank_in_Group':[1,2,3,1,2]}, index = [0,0,0,1,1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

via `groupby()` and `cumcount()`:

```
df1['Rank_in_Group']=df1.groupby(df1.index).cumcount()+1
```

**OR**

via `map()` and `apply()`:

```
df['Rank_in_Group']=df['A'].map(lambda x:range(1,len(x)+1))
df1=df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

output of `df1` :

```
    A   Rank_in_Group
0   e       1
0   g       2
0   p       3
1   c       1
1   x       2
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```
>>> df1['Rank_in_Group'] = df1.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
>>> df1
   A  Rank_in_Group
0  e              0
0  g              1
0  p              2
1  c              0
1  x              1
```

`level=0` allows to use the index as grouping, since the dataframe rows that come from the same list initially share the same index.